# Do both players need to own Legacy of the Void to play co-op missions?

Tags: starcraft-2

I want to play the Co-Op missions with my friend, but he's on the fence about getting LOTV. I know back when HOTS released Blizzard added a feature that made anyone in your party "own" your expansion for purposes of multiplayer. I'm wondering if that still applies to the Co-Op mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to a post on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/3s93ub/lotv_isnt_required_to_play_coop_missions/) it appears it is not needed to play co-op mode.

The key points in the post are:

> The Co-op Missions feature is available for everyone, regardless of
>   which version of StarCraft II you're playing. This also includes
>   Starter Edition players.
>
> You gain access to Swann, Vorazun and Zagara as additional Commanders
>   if you purchase Legacy of the Void.

In a separate thread found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Games/comments/3s844p/starcraft_ii_legacy_of_the_void_first/), a user says that if you party up with a friend that owns LotV, you get full access as long as you stay in party, so you'd be able to play the 3 commanders not included normally.